# how can i daynamic nav menu for this code in Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am learning Wordpress together with css and html and i don't know how to prepare menu for following code

html menu code:

```
<div class="main-menu-wrap style1">
<div class="menu-close xl-none">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="las la-times"></i></a>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="main-menu list-style">
    <li><a href="contact.html">Home</a></li>

        <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu list-style">
                <li>
                    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="service-details.html">Single Service</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

for this code i am using in my wordpress themes

```
    <?php
    wp_nav_menu(
    array(
    'menu'                 => 'primary',
    'container'            => 'div',
    'container_class'      => 'main-menu-wrap style1',
    'menu_class'           => 'main-menu list-style',
    'menu_id'              => 'menu',
    'add_li_class'         => 'has-children',
    'echo'                 => true,
)
); ?>
```

Comment: have you created a menu in  Appearance » Menus and make it location primary?

Comment: Yes i created a menu Appearance » Menus

Comment: Try out the code in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the add_li_class. this argument in not available in wp_nav_menu() official reference.

You have to register your menu using register_nav_menus().

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'nav_menu_register_cb' );
function nav_menu_register_cb(){
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'card2play' ),
        )
    );
}

   wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'menu'                 => 'primary',
        'container'            => 'div',
        'container_class'      => 'main-menu-wrap style1',
        'menu_class'           => 'main-menu list-style',
        'menu_id'              => 'menu',
        'echo'                 => true,
        'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
    )
);
```

Reference :- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menu/

Comment: Drop down menu not working